# Kafka AVRO cant send value as date

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

i have a avro schema :

```
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "errortime",
    "type": [ "null", {
      "type": "long",
      "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
    }]
```

which create java class with  field as joda DateTime errortime.

When i try to serialise to avro format i get the next error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type org.joda.time.DateTime: 2018-05-02T12:32:27.563Z
```

How to avoid this problem ?

Comment: how do you create your avro object and how are you serializing? are you using schemaregistry + KafkaAvroSerializer? or DatumWriter ?

Comment: hi. for creating java avro object i use gradle plugin (com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro)  for serializing i use KafkaAvroSerializer() with kafka registry

Comment: my first question was more about how are you instancing your avro class (creating the object) which is being serialized. how do you populate the date field? have u tried to replicate this like an unit test?

Comment: this problem not in my code the problem is in kafka jdbc sink connector

Comment: i would  be useful see your code and provide all the error log ..

Comment: i find that this a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1891. but if you know how to solve i will provide all information

Comment: Had the same issue, for a workaround Check the solution posted [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/avro-user/201608.mbox/%3CCAM+bZhgfvgSz=d=6KJ9FkbE5wuNkBbW=+jaH5q4d4jd0JvmHUw@mail.gmail.com%3E)